# My printer and computer quit playing nice

Tags: printing

We have an epson-wp-4530 which worked well enough with this computer for a couple of years.

We had a power outage and all hell broke loose. I was able to commence communications with the printer, but all it would print was a couple characters over and over and over again.

I got the latest deb 64 bit driver, installed and rebooted, and now it is printing a lot more complicated gibberish instead of test pages and whatnot that i am trying to print.

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. Printer driver: epson-201113w

Comment: Are you sure it's not a printer fault? Try a different printer, or try the existing printer on a different machine.

Comment: the printer is playing nice with my husband's windows 10 computer. usually both computers can happily work with this printer